# No SMB entries in Windows 7 Registry - Is it normal?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, smb

In light of WannaCry ransomware threat, my internet search indicates two actions to protect my Windows 7 OS

1. Install KB4012212 patch
2. Disable SMB1.0 & 2.0

I have installed KB4012212 and when I tried to disable SMB in the registry, I find that there’s no such entry by the name SMB1 & SMB2 REG-DWORD at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters`

Is it normal not to have SMB entries in the registry?

Could it be that the patch has removed those entries?

Should I create the two entries in registry and set them to Disabled state?

Thanks.

Comment: The instructions are slightly inaccurate – disabling SMB 2.0 is a bad idea, as it basically leaves the service useless (since there are no protocols left). If you don't use the file sharing service, then better just disable the service entirely.

Comment: It's not uncommon for default values to not exist. So you could create them and test whenever it's working.

Comment: Your doing it incorrectly: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1,-smbv2,-and-smbv3-in-windows-vista,-windows-server-2008,-windows-7,-windows-server-2008-r2,-windows-8,-and-windows-server-2012